# jQuery wrap a div around a massive block of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched `.wrap()`, `.append()`, `.wrapall()`, and `.insertAfter()` and haven't found solutions. I would like to take a new `div` and wrap it around a block of html. I have no access to the HTML so I need to use jQuery.

The `.insertAfter()` function was ideal, but unfortunately it closes the html tags automatically.

The root of the problem is that I need to center two separate `div`s that I have no access over their HTML.

```
$(function () {  
    $('<div id="centerContainer">').insertAfter('#header');
    $('</div><!-- centerContainer -->').insertAfter('#footer');
});
```

Comment: Is the problem you’re wanting to wrap HTML around two (or more) adjacent HTML elements?

Comment: I have one div and another div that ideally I want to float each. Then this div I want to insert in will give it a width and margin auto. Centering them.

Comment: Can you post the block of HTML (feel free to omit the contents) you want to wrap the `<div>` around, just so I can get a feel for the page mark-up?

Comment: `<body><div id="sidebar"></div> <div id="default"></div></body>`

And I need the sidebar on the right and default on left and then center both in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how DOM functions, `.insertAfter()` adds elements to the DOM not strings in that way, you should select all the elements and then call `.wrapAll()` on the returned collection.

Assuming(*based on the posted code*) all the elements between the `#header` and `#footer` elements(*if fact their siblings*) should be wrapped with another element you can use `.nextUntil()` for selecting next siblings of the `#header` until the `#footer` element and then call `.wrapAll()` on the returned collection:

```
$('#header').nextUntil('#footer').wrapAll('<div id="centerContainer"></div>');
```

Comment: I tried adding multiple elements in the wrapAll but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Your update is perfect. This works. NextUntil() saved the day. Thanks a lot!